# How to fix a div to the bottom-right of another div? (fiddle)

Tags: html, css, position, css-position, positioning

couldn't find a topic exactly about my problem.

I have these two divs, [DEMO here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/vfrL7qub/1/):

```
<div id="green"></div>
<div class="tab">Tab</div>
```

I want the tab to be fixed to the bottom right of the green div, in a specific position:

0px distance from the top of the green div (which I think is the default anyway),

and 50px distance from the right edge of that green div.

CSS:

```
#green {
    width:1020px;
    height:200px;
    background:green;
}

.tab {
    background-color: #EEE;
    width: 150px;
    height: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: .77em;
    padding-top: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 465px;
    border: 1px solid #E9E0E1;
    border-top: 0;
}
```

In the demo you can see that once you resize the window, the tab is moving away.
I actually found this out while browsing my test page with my Iphone, as all my desktop browsers windows were maximized so I couldn't even notice it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply replace your `right` property with `left:0px;`

Check the [DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/vfrL7qub/4/)

Comment: I don't know how it's working on the demo, but in my complete website It doesn't work. can you explain the sense in changing right to left to solve this?

Comment: Try to put these two boxes into another one (like `.wrapper` )and set the `position:relative` property to this. Here is the complete code --> [DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/vfrL7qub/6/)

Comment: Thanks! works with the wrapper.. what's the explanation for this?

Comment: There is pretty good explanation - [LINK](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)

Answer (score 0):

Updated Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/vfrL7qub/9/

Wrap the two divs into a container div with `position:relative`.

For your tab position it with

```
top:0;
margin-right:50px;
```

Comment: Ah, you wanted the tab in the _bottom_ right. New fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/vfrL7qub/10/